# Linear Regression using RNN tensorflow python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression, recurrent-neural-network

Can anyone please site an example on how linear regression can be implemented using RNN in pure tensorflow other than using keras API..

Eg :

```
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I ll divide them into 5 batches of 2 element each so x_train will be of shape [5, 2]

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]..

y_train = [3, 5, 7,...]
```

Where the challenge is that.. i should be giving the model to train upon 1 and 2 then from that the model should have and inference of 3, like wise 3 and 4 and it should prediction 5.. and so on.. I have tried a way around but had problems with shape and the losses where really high..

The same problem in a deep network works perfect with around 100 epochs, 100 data points and a loss of 0.01 (MSE).

Can anyone please help me..?